# How to clear the value of getIntent().getAction()

Tags: android

I'm launching an activity using shortcut and performing some operations. I want to set empty value to getIntent().getAction()

```
private static final String SHORT_CUT_MY_BARCODE = "android.intent.action.VIEW.myBarCode";

if (SHORT_CUT_MY_BARCODE.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        //do something
}

// todo need to clear getIntent().getAction() here.
```

Comment: Question is why do you want to do it.

Comment: i'm launching a pop-up if i'm coming from shortcut and upon closing i'm returning to activity (onCreate called). this got me stuck in an infinite loop(pop-up) is opening again and again.

Comment: You can set a flag to handle that condition. Also I dont think your onCreate would be called again if you close your pop up

Comment: you can use one flag for that, when first time pop-up open set that flag value to 1, and check flag==0 if true than open pop-up else no need do to anything.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify the `Intent` that was used to start the activity, sorry.